# Area of curve rotating around y-axis

Tags: calculus

Calculate the volume when  $$\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{2}=1 \; \;(*)$$ is rotated around the y-axis.

I have done x-axis rotations with simple functions. This one is harder for me. This is an *ellipse* and I know where it cuts the x and y-axis. If i were to solve for y, then I'd get ±√ and then break it up into two cases. But then I realise The +case hase the same volume as the -case.

My attempt is $$Volume =2 \int_{-2}^{2} x^2 \pi dy$$ and then solve for $x^2$ in (*) expression. The two is there because the +case and the -case is the same, and I want the whole volume.

Comment: There is no need for the 2 (Notice the solid generated by just the positive part is already the solid we want; multiplying by 2 will result in "double-counting"). Except for that part your attempt is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2 = 1 - 2y^2\\
V=\pi\int_{-\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 2}x^2dy$$

You would only be rotating 1/2 of the ellipse